# Javascript - have text appear with an image when clicked on

Tags: javascript

I have just started with Javascript/HTML and am wondering how I could create a page that has say, 2 images on and when you click on an image text relevant to that image appears?
My images are listed as below:

```
<img class="thumb" data-ord="1"  onclick='changeMainImg(this);' src="full/01.jpg">
```

My changeMainImg function:

```
function changeMainImg1(that) {
  document.getElementById("fullview").src=that.src;
  current=that;}
```

Can I implement the text in the function so that each of the two different images has its own text?

Thank you

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you share some demo of what you are up to?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. If text is short, you can add it as a `dataset` attribute in the same img tag like this:

```html
<img class="thumb" data-ord="1" data-text="my text" onclick='changeMainImg(this);' src="full/01.jpg">
```

```js
function changeMainImg1(that) {

    document.getElementById("fullview").innerHTML = that.dataset.text;
}
```

Other way is to define a variable with all texts and call it by index:

```html
<img class="thumb" data-ord="0" onclick='changeMainImg(this);' src="full/01.jpg">
```

```js
var texts = [
    'text 1',
    'text 2'
];

function changeMainImg1(that) {

    document.getElementById("fullview").innerHTML = texts[that.dataset.ord];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume displaying the src attribute works for you. Below a possible solution. Prerequisite is to assign the same class name to each image involved.

```js
/* Store image elements in an array */
const images = [... document.getElementsByClassName('thumb')];
/* Assign event listener to each image element */
images.map( (image) => image.addEventListener( "click", function() 
  { alert(image.src) }
));
```

```html
<img class="thumb" data-ord="1" src="full/01.jpg">
<img class="thumb" data-ord="2" src="full/02.jpg">
<img class="thumb" data-ord="2" src="full/03.jpg">
<img class="thumb" data-ord="2" src="full/04.jpg">
<img class="thumb" data-ord="2" src="full/05.jpg">
```